# Getting: Type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter

When I run this project emulator gave me error like this "type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'" and I can't find the problem but I  think there is no problem with syntax. Is there any way to fix my problem?

```
Future<void> _asyncInputDialog(
  BuildContext context, String aimagId, String aimagName) async {
String? teamName;
return showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: false,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text(aimagName ?? 'Default Name'),
      content: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Баталгаажуулах код',
                hintText: 'код оруулна уу',
              ),
              onChanged: (value) {
                teamName = value.isNotEmpty ? value : null;
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      actions: [
        TextButton(
          child: Text('ХААХ'),
          onPressed: () {
            Get.back();
          },
        ),
        TextButton(
          child: Text('OK'),
          onPressed: () async {
            await controller.getConnectionData(
              aimagId,
              teamName ?? 'String Value is Null',
              '',
            );
            if (controller.status == "1") {
              Get.back();
            }
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);
}
```

Comment: Where does the error appear in your code?

Comment: I think it is on teamName

Comment: onChanged: (value) {
               if(teamName != null && value?.isNotEmpty == true) {
                       teamName = value!;
               }

              },

Try this

Comment: Seeing that you put `Text(aimagName ?? 'Default Name')` in your code implies that you think `aimagName` can be `null` but that's impossible since the parameter is defined as `String aimagName`. Maybe you actually passing `null` to the function and in that case you need to define it as `String? aimagName`

Comment: teamName shouldn't be a null right?

Comment: I am a new guy on flutter and working on a old project

Comment: Where is `_asyncInputDialog` invoked? Please include the full error with stack trace.

Comment: _asyncInputDialog is coming like this => onChanged: (connData? data) async {
                                controller.selectedAimag.value = data!;
                                await _asyncInputDialog(
                                  context,
                                  data.id.toString(),
                                  data.name.toString(),
                                );
                              },

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
Future<void> _asyncInputDialog(
  BuildContext context, String aimagId, String aimagName) async {
String? teamName;
return showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: false,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text(aimagName.isEmpty ? 'Default Name' : aimagName),
      content: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Баталгаажуулах код',
                hintText: 'код оруулна уу',
              ),
              onChanged: (value) {
                teamName = value.isNotEmpty ? value : null;
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      actions: [
        TextButton(
          child: Text('ХААХ'),
          onPressed: () {
            Get.back();
          },
        ),
        TextButton(
          child: Text('OK'),
          onPressed: () async {
            await controller.getConnectionData(
              aimagId.isEmpty ? "DefaultID" : aimagId,
              teamName ?? 'String Value is Null',
              '',
            );
            if (controller.status == "1") {
              Get.back();
            }
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);
}
```

you need to provide default-Id if aimagId is empty.

Comment: can you fix it for full code please?

Comment: I have made edits to my previous answer. Please review the changes and see if the updated solution works for you.                                                       aimagName & aimagId both are defined as a String, not a String? so if aimagName or aimagId is null then you need to check it out as I added in the solution.

Comment: aimagName & aimagId both are not a String